# How to save date select fields in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I save date select field?

Say, I have this in my views:

```
 <%= f.date_select :dob, :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1920 %>
```

This would be converted to HTML as :

```
<select id="user_dob_1i" name="user[dob(1i)]"> ..for year..

<select id="user_dob_2i" name="user[dob(2i)]"> ..for month..

<select id="user_dob_3i" name="user[dob(3i)]"> ..for date..
```

Above select value will of-course have some options.

Now, when I submit the page/form, parameters will be passed as:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"dob(1i)"=>"2015", "dob(2i)"=>"3", "dob(3i)"=>"24"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
```

Make sense?

In my database, I have field called 'dob'. Question is how do I save this field in my database?

I am using Rails 4.0.2 and using the params permit feature. I have added this in my controller,

```
params.require(:user).permit("dob(1i)", "dob(2i)", "dob(3i)")
```

Googled about it but I did not reach fair conclusion on it..

Comment: What the problem with `params.require(:user).permit(:dob)`?

Comment: I get this : 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [2015, 3, 24] to dob (wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1))]

Although I understand that this message has nothing to do with permit but to be on safer side, I learnt that pass them explicitly.

Comment: [the actual problem was the value in database was on VARCHAR, and instead it should be DATE. check it please.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18211789/2057388)

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a date from the three params:

```
@user.dob = Date.new(params['dob(1i)'].to_i,params['dob(2i)'].to_i,params['dob(3i)'].to_i)

@user.save
```

Just FYI, Rails will accept an actual string as a date for a column in the DB of type `DATE`. So if you use a date picker that returns a string like:

```
# if params[dob] = '2015-3-26' passed from your form
@user.dob = params[dob]
@user.save
  # in server console you'll see...
  # SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "dob" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 193  [["dob", Thu, 26 Mar 2015],...
```

So you could do something like:

```
@user.dob = params.values.join'-'
  # =>'2015-3-26'
@user.save
```

Of course if you add any other params to your form and your `permit`, then that one would no longer work. I advise you look at date-pickers for your forms. Makes everything easy.

Comment: [`Date::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new) take a integer as arguments in `params` you have a string.

Comment: the form does not return integer, never. It always string.

Comment: this is good simple hack. +1. But should be `params['dob(1i)'].to_i` instead raise error `undef method dob`.